# Trying to parse a date, review output, and verify it shows between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IF(AND(XLOOKUP(A2,Ticket_Import!B:B,LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,10))>=DATE(2020,7,1)),"Yes","No")
```

This is my formula, this will be part of it, only because once I get this part working, the other half which will be between 2020,9,30 will be the cutoff date.

But here are the cells being used.

A2 is a ticket number in this case 467, it looks up the ticket in row A:A of "Ticket Import" then and comes back with 2020-05-16. As a result of referencing O:O.  I know this works becuase I have run:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,Ticket_Import!B:B,LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,10))
```

and it comes back with said date.

Now with the IF(AND()) in place, result should come back with "No" because 2020-05-16 is not greater than 2020,7,1, but instead it is saying "Yes".

Ultimately I want it to look between three-month variables.  Jan - March, April - June, July - Sept, and October - December.

Is the reason I can't get it working because it's missing the 2nd variable?

Because if it is, the formula should look like this:

```
=IF(AND(XLOOKUP(A2,Ticket_Import!B:B,LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,10))>=DATE(2020,4,1),XLOOKUP(A2,Ticket_Import!B:B,LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,10))<=DATE(2020,7,1)),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,10))` returns text and text is always greater than a number.  Convert the date to a true date:

```
=IF(AND(--XLOOKUP(A2,Ticket_Import!B:B,LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,10))>=DATE(2020,4,1),--XLOOKUP(A2,Ticket_Import!B:B,LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,10))<=DATE(2020,7,1)),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: I was always bad at math... that's why I use excel... why the --?

Comment: How do I do that? Truedate gives me an error saying too many variables?

Comment: just use `--` like I did.

Comment: Thanks for the tweak, why does that work? What does that exactly do?

Comment: It changes the string to a number by multiplying the string by `-1*-1`.  It is the same as `=--"45611"`  this will return `45611` as a number and not a string that looks like a number

Comment: I'm not used to running with that kind of logic in excel, thanks for that, I'll remember that... it will make some of my formulas less bulky in the future I feel.

Comment: `="45611">50000` will return `TRUE` but `=--"45611">50000` will return False because we convert the string to a number